Running Valgrind in Ceedling as a command hook
I'm running valgrind along with ceedling as instructed by Toby Webb text. Everything works ok when tests pass. However, upon a test failure or upon detecting a memory leak, Ceedling throws an error.
> Shell executed command:
`valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --errors-for-leak-kinds=all --error-exitcode=10 build/test/out/test_soc_soh_module/test_soc_soh_module.out`
> Produced output: 
test_soc_soh_module.c:24:test_calculates_soc_correctly:FAIL: Expected 13 Was 1

-----------------------
1 Tests 1 Failures 0 Ignored 
FAIL
==62521== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==62521== Copyright (C) 2002-2024, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==62521== Using Valgrind-3.24.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==62521== Command: build/test/out/test_soc_soh_module/test_soc_soh_module.out
==62521== 
==62521== 
==62521== HEAP SUMMARY:
==62521==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==62521==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4,096 bytes allocated
==62521== 
==62521== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==62521== 
==62521== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==62521== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
> And terminated with exit code: [1]

 ERROR: Exception raised in plugin `command_hooks` within build hook :post_test_fixture_execute
Plugin | CommandHooks > :post_test...
 EXCEPTION: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
 Ceedling could not complete operations because of errors
Plugin | CommandHooks > :post_error...

How can I fix this?
When I run the shell command independently, no errors are shown.
valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --errors-for-leak-kinds=all --error-exitcode=10 build/test/out/test_soc_soh_module/test_soc_soh_module.out
==62928== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==62928== Copyright (C) 2002-2024, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==62928== Using Valgrind-3.24.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==62928== Command: build/test/out/test_soc_soh_module/test_soc_soh_module.out
==62928== 
test_soc_soh_module.c:24:test_calculates_soc_correctly:FAIL: Expected 13 Was 1

-----------------------
1 Tests 1 Failures 0 Ignored 
FAIL
==62928== 
==62928== HEAP SUMMARY:
==62928==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==62928==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==62928== 
==62928== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==62928== 
==62928== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==62928== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)


“Valgrind (as you probably know) is a memory leak tester for C. We can easily configure Ceedling to run Valgrind.”. Sad face. Toby is telling us that he is clueless about what Valgrind does.

It looks like an error in Ceedling which I hadn’t even heard of until seeing this question. My first impression of Ceedling is that it is doing things the hard (and so probably unreliable) way. Most tools that I know that need to parse Valgrind output use the XML output.

@PaulFloyd I'm new to unit testing and I wanted to incorporate memory leak tests to my unit tests. That's when I came across Toby's article. Am I going in the right path or is there a better way to do this?

Doing any testing and using any tools is already a very positive sign. Don't be discouraged. It's hard to tell what is best for you. Don't worry too much about leaks. Concentrate on bounds errors and uninitialized memory first. Valgrind is generally fairly easy to use. Sanitizers are faster but need extra builds.
